# The parameters don't pass to the function

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

```
this.command.CommandText = "\"GetForeignKeysTable\"";
this.command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
this.command.Parameters.AddWithValue("tableName", resource);
FKDataTable.Load(this.command.ExecuteReader());
```

On the fourth line I get an error: GetForeignKeysTable(tableName := text) doesn't exist. PosrtgresSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "GetForeignKeysTable"(tableName text)
RETURNS TABLE ("FKFieldName" integer, "PKTableName" text) AS $$
BEGIN
 RETURN QUERY SELECT "Id", "FIO" FROM tableName;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Parameters cannot be used for fields or table names. They are used to express values for where clause or for values in insert/update

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a tablename as a parameter using dynamic sql. Notice it is generally not recomended.

Your sql should be a string, then you concatenate the received table name and then execute str sql string

```
.....create procedure etc etc etc .......

/* Build Transact-SQL String with parameter value */
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ' + myTable 
/* Execute Transact-SQL String */
EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
```

Comment: You've just introduce a *gigantic* security vulnerability.

Comment: It all depends on what you're feeding to your parameter. Using a computer isa "gigantic security vulnerability" by itself. I dont see people panicking. It is a feature. Not a vulnerability. Please chill out

Comment: Since apparently you don't care at all about security, and consider it something not worth even considering, why don't you reply with your full name, bank account numbers, social security number (or other applicable tax ID), full address, all credit count numbers, and billing addresses for those numbers.  Don't worry about posting all of that publicly, it's not a vulnerability.

Comment: @Servy: Not every piece of dynamic SQL is a security flaw. Something like `"SELECT * FROM " + (someCondition ? "a" : "b")` will never be a problem. You're only in trouble if you substitute values derived from user input.

Comment: @NickBarnes And yet this isn't using a fixed whitelist of values.  It's accepting an arbitrary value.

Comment: @Servy: We have no idea where this value is coming from. There's not a lot of context here...

Comment: @NickBarnes So, given that, don't you think suggesting something that's *enormously* dangerous unless you know, with certainty, that the input is in a whitelist of safe content, is unwise given that you don't have any idea whether or not the user is in that *very* specific situation?

Comment: @Servy, it would be easier if you suggest something instead of just attacking something that has already ben discussed until the end in the community.
Now, for the OP: Yeah, dont feed your stored procedure with dynamic sql stuff coming from user input. /and if you do, make sure you protect yourself from sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I MAY be full of sh*t here.. but I thought the param had to start with "@" IE "@tablename", also make sure "resource" is a string, not a class/whatever...